# Set background to a drawable programatically

Tags: android, xml, background

Here is my xml: It's called border_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/light_blue" />
    <solid android:color="@color/light_blue" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

I want to set this as background to my view programatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work:

```
 myview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_blue);
```