# How can I set an XML drawable as a background image programatically?

Tags: java, android, xml

I designed an image in xml, and put it under my drawable resources

**ic_receive.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,10.5016l19.5008,0l0,10.4968l-19.5008,0z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#C6ECCB"
      android:fillType="nonZero"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M4.5,3.0016l19.5,0l0,10.4968l-19.5,0z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#41BF53"
      android:fillType="nonZero"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M18,7.5l-3,0l0,-3l-1.5,0l0,3l-2.9992,0l0,1.5l2.9992,0l0,3l1.5,0l0,-3l3,0z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#C6ECCB"
      android:fillType="nonZero"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

I tried setting the image programatically in a Recycler View in my Fragment

**TransactionsFragment.java**

```
TransactionsModel options = new TransactionsModel("Approved", "$ 3,000", R.drawable.ic_receive, R.drawable.ic_action_home);
        transactionsList.add(options);
```

When I run the app, the ImageView turns out blank, but when  use a .png drawable, it shows fine, like the R.drawable.ic_action_home used for another ImageView.

**Note**

I also noticed that, the xml image shows fine in the tiny preview by the right of the code that sets the drawable

Other tutorials like this one([Set background to a drawable programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791270/set-background-to-a-drawable-programatically)), seemingly point to the same way of setting the drawable resource, but still not working for me.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this may be? could I have missed or omitted something?

BTW, I'm using the new AndroidX if that matters and can also provide more code if needed.

Cheers!

**EDIT**

Code used to display the image in recycler view

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        TransactionsModel movie = transactionsList.get(position);
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(movie.getTxIcon())
                .into(holder.txIcon);

    }
```

Comment: please post the code you're using in order to display the image in the recyclerview.

Comment: I think your vector file is broken, use another SVG file and test again, you can download the SVG icon from flaticon.com for free.

Comment: @Lino please see updated code

Comment: @AradSheybak no it's not it shows in the app if i set it through `android:src="@drawable/ic_receive"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to set drawable as a background.

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgg);
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.bgg);
```